# React-native route rendering multiple times and messing up state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-state, asyncstorage

I wanted to create a like function for my job-app. But the liked state always had strange values and the like functionality was not working. I figured that it might be because the route component in [id].js was rendered five times for some reason.

The like function should first check if the current job is already in async storage and set the liked state depending on that. It also should change on button press and add or remove the current job from async storage. But in my implementation the like state always returns unexpected values

For example the liked state always returned false in the useEffect function, but It also was false after setLiked(!liked).

[id].js

```
import { Text, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, RefreshControl } from "react-native";
import { Stack, useRouter, useGlobalSearchParams } from "expo-router";
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

import { JobAbout, JobFooter, Company, JobTabs, ScreenHeaderBtn, Specifics } from "../../components";
import { COLORS, icons, SIZES } from "../../constants";
import useFetch from "../../hook/useFetch";
import { getLikedJobs } from "../../utils";

const tabs = ["About", "Qualifications", "Responsibilities"];

export default function JobDetails() {
    
    const params = useGlobalSearchParams();
    const router = useRouter();

    const { data, isLoading, error, refetch } = useFetch("job-details", {
        job_id: params.id
    });

    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(tabs[0]);

    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
        setRefreshing(true);
        refetch()
        setRefreshing(false)
    }, []);

    const displayTabContent = () => {
        console.log("display switch")
        switch (activeTab) {
            case "About":
                return <JobAbout info={data[0].job_description ?? "No data provided"} />
            case "Qualifications":
                return <Specifics 
                    title="Qualifications"
                    points={data[0].job_highlights?.Qualifications ?? ["No data provided"]}
                />
            case "Responsibilities":
                return <Specifics 
                    title="Responsibilities"
                    points={data[0].job_highlights?.Responsibilities ?? ["No data provided"]}
            />
        }
    }


    console.log("render");

    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite}}>
            <Stack.Screen options={{
                headerStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.lightWhite },
                headerShadowVisible: false,
                headerBackVisible: false,
                headerLeft: () => (
                    <ScreenHeaderBtn 
                        iconUrl={icons.left}
                        dimension="60%"
                        handlePress={() => router.back()}
                    />
                ),
                headerRight: () => (
                    <ScreenHeaderBtn 
                        iconUrl={icons.share}
                        dimension="60%"
                    />
                ),
                headerTitle: "",
            }}/>

            <>              
                <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />} >
                    { isLoading ? (
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" colors={COLORS.primary}/>
                    ) : error ? (
                        <Text>Something went wrong</Text>
                    ) : data.length === 0 ? (
                        <Text>No data</Text>
                    ) : (
                        <View style={{ padding: SIZES.medium, paddingBottom: 100 }}>
                            <Company 
                                companyLogo={data[0].employer_logo}
                                jobTitle={data[0].job_title}
                                companyName={data[0].employer_name}
                                location={data[0].job_country}
                            />
                            <JobTabs 
                                tabs={tabs}
                                activeTab={activeTab}
                                setActiveTab={setActiveTab}
                            />

                            {displayTabContent()}
                        </View>
                    )}
                </ScrollView>
                
                <JobFooter url={data[0]?.job_google_link ?? "https://careers.google.com/jobs/results"} id={params.id} data={data}/>
                
            </>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Footer.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Image, Linking } from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import styles from './footer.style'
import { icons } from '../../../constants'
import { getLikedJobs } from '../../../utils'

const Footer =  ({ url, id, data }) => {

  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("Use effect call");
    const initializeLiked = async () => {
      try {
        const likedJobs = await getLikedJobs();
        const isLiked = likedJobs.some(job => job.job_id === id);
        setLiked(isLiked);
        //console.log(liked + " init")
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    initializeLiked();
  }, [id]);
  
  const handleLikeChange = async () => {
    setLiked(prevLiked => !prevLiked);

    setTimeout(() => {
      //console.log(liked);
    }, 0);

    let likedJobs = await getLikedJobs();
  
    if (liked) {
      likedJobs.push([data]);
    } else {
      const updatedJobs = likedJobs.filter(job => job[0].job_id !== id);
      likedJobs = updatedJobs;
    }
  
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("liked-jobs", JSON.stringify(likedJobs));
  };

  const handlePress = async () => {
    handleLikeChange();
  };

  console.log("Footer render")

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.likeBtn} onPress={handlePress}>
          <Image 
            source={liked ? icons.heart : icons.heartOutline}
            resizeMode='contain'
            style={styles.likeBtnImage}
          />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.applyBtn} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url)}>
        <Text style={styles.applyBtnText}>Apply</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Footer
```